# Verb that goes with 'A case study has been...'?

Tags: verbs, synonyms

I am submitting an abstract to a conference today, and I need to lose 1 word to stay under the 200 word limit. I'm trying to shorten this sentence, by replacing 'carried out'  with something different.

*A case study has been carried out successfully.*

So far I have come up with 'performed', 'conducted', 'executed', but I am not sure whether this is entirely correct. I am not entirely sure if you can conduct or perform a case study. You conduct research, but not a case study, right? Anyway, I've read it here and there but it does not look perfect to me, and even if it is right, is it common to say you have conducted or performed something successfully? Same goes for executed, which I think does not sound very scientific or at least is not often used in this context.

Because it is such a short summary I'd like to hit the nail on the head and not make any grammatical mistakes or mistakes in the exact meaning of words.

Comment: You may refer here as to the more common term used: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=conduct+a+study%2C+execute+a+study%2C+carry+out+a+study%2C+perform+a+study&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconduct%20a%20study%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cexecute%20a%20study%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccarry%20out%20a%20study%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cperform%20a%20study%3B%2Cc0

Comment: _Carried out_ and _conducted_ are both fine. _Performed_ is a bit odd, but perfectly understandable. _Executed_ would make me think—in jest, of course—that the participants in the case study had all been shot, which I rather hope isn’t the actual outcome of your case study. (If it is, do remind me never to sign up for any of your case studies!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Conducted" was the first thing that came to my mind when I've read the beginning of your sentence. I think it could be used without a problem.

I think that you could remove "succesfully" from your sentence. An unsuccessful study wouldn't be in the abstract.

Answer (score 1):

I would use 'completed' as in a case study has been completed. You could say 'a case study has been successfully completed'. This implies progress, is less dry and takes you with some energy and enthusiasm to the next step... hopefully bringing others along with you!

Carried out - tells us that the study is done - but does not allude to... results.

Completed - implies more that we got something out of it. It also says that it is - well - complete - finished and well-rounded in some way.

Successfully completed - definitely implies that the study brought useful or interesting results, and conveys - enthusiasm and excitement ( a trait not necessarily always possessed by - case studies!)